# how to use date and time picker in android and what is the error that i have and how to fix it

Tags: android, datepicker, syntax-error

I am a creating a simple android application that use `date and time picker` but the system give me an syntax error how to fix this error ??

The app allow the user to select a date and time than the it will be displayed in a `TextView`

the error is :   in the onclick method in the if statement **dialogpick** and **timepick**     the error say : **timepick/dialogpick  cannot be resolved to a variable**

## MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.datetime;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    // btn1=time btn2=date
    Button btn1, btn2;
    TextView txtv;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat dt = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        txtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);

        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dialogpick = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthofyear,
                    int dayofmonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthofyear);
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayofmonth);
                updateText();

            }

            private void updateText() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        };
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timepick = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourofday, int minute) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourofday);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                updateText();

            }

            private void updateText() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        };

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {

            new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, dialogpick,
                    cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    cal.get(Calendar.MONDAY)).show();
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
            new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, timepick,
                    cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
                    .show();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: in which line you are getting the error?

Comment: in the onclick method in the if statement **dialogpick** and **timepick**     the error say : **timepick/dialogpick  cannot be resolved to a variable**

Comment: Use differnet method names instead of same name updateText. And place these methods outside.

Comment: @Kanwaljit Singh  i did as you said  i change the instance  but still the same error

Comment: ok see the answer given by laalto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timepick = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
```

`timepick` is a local variable in `onCreate()`. You cannot access local variables in another method such as `onClick()`.

You can move the declaration and instantiation of `timepick` to class member level, that is outside of `onCreate()`. You can access member fields from all instance methods.

The same goes for `dialogpick`.